# Operating on existing bootstrap switches

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

If I have a bunch of bootstrap switches on some page, and I want to toggle each one that is disabled to enabled, how can I access the bootstrapswitch functionality?

```
$('.boostrap-switch input').each(function(i, e){
   var mySwitch = e;
   if(!e.state)
      e.toggleState();
});
```

Not sure how to access bootstrapswitch methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.boostrap-switch input').each(function(i, e){
   var mySwitch = $(e).data('bootstrapSwitch');
   if(!mySwitch.state())
      mySwitch.toggleState();
});
```

Comment: Well, you could have at least accepted my answer than deleting the whole question.